# Java print decimal points of numbers

Tags: java, integer

I am currently working on a Java Program where the user inputs how much money they want to put away, how long it will be away and the interest rate.

I'm a Beginner with Java so don't make me look stupid if its simple.

This is not a duplicate as I wasn't asking the difference between a float and a double in fact I didn't even know what a double/float was. I was just asking for a way for it to show the decimal values with the whole number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JaxonBruns_Money
{
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    System.out.println("Jaxon Bruns, April 3rd 2017");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);      

    System.out.println("How much Money?");
    int amountofmoney = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How long, in years?");
    int years = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Interest Rate?");
    int rate = in.nextInt();

    int [] myarr = new int[years];
    System.out.println("Years          Money");
    System.out.println("*************************");
    for (int i = 0; i <= myarr.length; i++) {
        int moneygained = amountofmoney * rate;
        amountofmoney = amountofmoney + moneygained;
        System.out.println(i + amountofmoney);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Use [`float`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html)/[`double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) instead of int.

Comment: It is advised to go with BigDecimal for monetary calculations against floating points for the sake of precision. You could read it as nextDouble() as opposed to nextInt() as mentioned in the other comment, but once read, better to calculate as BigDecimal values.

Comment: Ill try that. Thanks

Comment: It’s hardly a duplicate, @Mistalis, but it’s a helpful link certainly, thank you.

Comment: What are you guys meaning about duplicate

Comment: A duplicate is when you are asking a question that has been asked before (obviously this is most interesting if it was also answered some other time it was asked).